# Create XML doc using LINQ to XML with foreach loop

Tags: xml, foreach, linq-to-xml

I am creating an XML document using LINQ to XML. Here is what I have:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("requestor",
                    new XAttribute("system", system),
                    new XAttribute("tracking", doc.batchId + i),
                    new XAttribute("receipt", "N"),
                    new XElement("repository",
                        new XAttribute("type", "filenet"),
                        new XElement("document",
                            new XAttribute("docclass", class),
                            new XElement("file",
                                new XElement("location",
                                new XAttribute("path", doc.imagePath))),
                            new XElement("indices",
                                new XElement("index",
                                    new XAttribute("name", "CaseNum"),
                                    new XAttribute("value", doc.caseNumber)),
                                new XElement("index",
                                    new XAttribute("name", "ProvName"),
                                    new XAttribute("value", doc.name)),
                                new XElement("index",
                                    new XAttribute("name", "DOS"),
                                    new XAttribute("value", doc.date)))))));
```

My problem is that I need to create multipe file nodes. I have a list of string and I need to create a file node for each item in the list. Can I put a foreach loop in middle of the XDocument declaration? If not, whats the best way to do this?

I tried doing it by adding a blank file node, and then afterwards adding this:

```
foreach (string path in pathList)
                {
                    xmlDoc.Add(new XElement("location",
                                 new XAttribute("path", path)));
                }
```

But I don't know how to specify that this should go under the file node.

I would also like to know if the way I am approaching this task is ideal or if there is a more optimal way of doing it. I am fairly new to LINQ and quite new to XML so I don't know if this way is open to bugs/errors etc.

(Please forgive me if my question is quite simple. I am new to all this and that is why I am turning to you, the experts. I am trying to learn. Thanks!)

---

Requested Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <requestor system="CMWFS" tracking="1320530011" receipt="N">
- <repository type="filenet">
- <document docclass="abc"
- <file>
  <location path="myPath1" /> 
  </file>
- <file>
  <location path="myPath2" /> 
  </file>
- <file>
  <location path="myPath3" /> 
  </file>
- <file>
  <location path="myPath4" /> 
  </file>
- <file>
  <location path="myPath5" /> 
  </file>
- <file>
  <location path="myPath6" /> 
  </file>
- <file>
  <location path="myPath7" /> 
  </file>
- <indices>
  <index name="CaseNum" value="" /> 
  <index name="ProvName" value="" /> 
  <index name="DOS" value="7/24/2013" /> 
  </indices>
  </document>
  </repository>
  </requestor>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the requested output?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan forgive me for my ignorance but I don't understand. Can you please explain or provide a link to an article explaining what you mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this out:**

```
//initialize list
String[] list_of_items = { "item_01", "item_02", "item_03", 
                           "item_04", "item_05", "item_06", 
                           "item_07", "item_08", "item_09", 
                           "item_10", "item_11", "item_12" };

//initialize XML-string (more readable form as no nested element declaration)
String xml_string = @"<requestor system=""CMWFS"" tracking=""1320530011"" receipt=""N"">
                         <repository type=""filenet"">
                            <document docclass=""abc"">
                               <indices>
                                  <index name=""CaseNum"" value=""""/>
                                  <index name=""ProvName"" value=""""/>
                                  <index name=""DOS"" value=""7/24/2013""/>
                               </indices>
                            </document>
                         </repository>
                      </requestor>";

//prepare XDocument
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml_string);

//start looping
foreach (String item in list_of_items) {
    XElement file = new XElement("file");              //file container
    XElement location = new XElement("location");      //location container
    location.Add(new XAttribute("path", item));        //adding attribute
    file.Add(location);                                //adding location to file
    xDoc.Descendants("document").First()
        .Elements("indices").First()
        .AddBeforeSelf(file);                          //adding file to document
}
Console.Write(xDoc);                                   //showing resultant
```

Hope this helps.